# One way direction Question->Answer some link?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing follows post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224573/internal-server-error-when-running-website-on-windows-server-2012/14305805#14305805

In this case you can see, that the answer to this question was "I have the same problem". I would like to ref my comment, but I could not found this in FAQ or somewhere else that this is one direction (Question -> Answer, Answer, Answer).

Is there somewhere a link where this is explained that I can ref?

Comment: The new about page will be good for that once it is deployed (example on Super User: http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to the FAQ. While the answer is not yet deleted, it ultimately will be. And its reason is explained in the section ["Why are some questions or answers removed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). This is after all "Not an answer". And feel free to flag it as such.